# GeoTools KML export with Document@name

Tags: kml, geotools

I've been able to export features as KML using GeoTools. However, I would like to insert a `name` attribute at the top level (e.g. `Document`, though a `Folder` would be fine too). (Example of what I'd like at the end.)

This is what I am getting so far:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml:kml xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
         xmlns:xal="urn:oasis:names:tc:ciq:xsdschema:xAL:2.0"
         xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"
         xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <kml:Document id="area-418e1090-6ca8-4e34-a563-9c36db53cb35">
        <!-- would like "name" here -->
        <kml:Placemark id="shape-1">
            <kml:ExtendedData/>
            <kml:Polygon>
                <kml:outerBoundaryIs>
                    <kml:LinearRing>
                        <kml:coordinates>0.0,0.0 0.0,20.0 20.0,20.0 20.0,0.0 0.0,0.0</kml:coordinates>
                    </kml:LinearRing>
                </kml:outerBoundaryIs>
            </kml:Polygon>
        </kml:Placemark>
        <kml:Placemark id="shape-2">
            ... et cetera

        </kml:Placemark>
    </kml:Document>
</kml:kml>
```

The code for that I've scraped together from a bunch of examples, it boils down to this:

```java
ArrayList<SimpleFeature> list = new ArrayList<>();
addShapes(entity, list);

DefaultFeatureCollection featureCollection = new DefaultFeatureCollection(id("area", entity.getUuid()), null);
featureCollection.addAll(list);

OutputStream outputStream = httpServletResponse.getOutputStream();
encoder.encode(featureCollection, KML.kml, outputStream);
```

And:

```java
private void addShapes(AbstractAreaEntity entity, ArrayList<SimpleFeature> list) {
    List<Geometry> shapes = entity.getShapes();
    for (int i = 0; i < shapes.size(); i++) {
        Geometry geometry = shapes.get(i);
        list.add(new SimpleFeatureImpl(singletonList(geometry), shapeType, new FeatureIdImpl(id("shape", i + 1))));
    }
}
```

This is what I would like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml:kml xmlns:xs=...>
    <kml:Document id="area-418e1090-6ca8-4e34-a563-9c36db53cb35">
        <kml:name>My Document With Placemarks</kml:name> <!-- this! -->
        <kml:Placemark id="shape-1">
            ... et cetera

        </kml:Placemark>
    </kml:Document>
</kml:kml>
```

It appears that `Encoder.encode` only works with a `FeatureCollection` implementation, and it does not seem I can set properties or attributes on it (like `name`).

Comment: What do you mean by "only works with a `FeatureCollection` implementation"? Did you mean a `DefaultFeatureCollection`?

Comment: `DefaultFeatureCollection` _is_ an implementation of the `FeatureCollection` interface, so I was just speaking in more-general terms. My point there was that, since we are restricted to using _that_, I can't set the `name` on whatever goes into the encoder, which makes it seem like the interface of the encoder doesn't lend itself to what I want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, here's a "solution" since I could not dwel on this any longer. (Not really a *solution*, it's more a workaround.) If there's anyone with a real solution, I am still hoping to swap it out.

Updated the code that calls the encoder:

```java
OutputStream outputStream = httpServletResponse.getOutputStream();
// this can be restored once there's a solution for this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/328675
// also see the comment in the class NameInsertingDataWriter's source file
//encoder.encode(featureCollection, KML.kml, outputStream);
encoder.encode(featureCollection, KML.kml, new NameInsertingDataWriter(outputStream, entity.getName()));
```

The encoder is now given an implementation of `org.xml.sax.ContentHandler` (instead of the `OutputStream` directly); delegating to the following:

```java
import com.sun.xml.bind.marshaller.DataWriter;
import org.geotools.feature.FeatureCollection;
import org.geotools.xsd.Encoder;
import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.AttributesImpl;

import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;

/**
 * Where {@link Encoder#encode(Object, QName, OutputStream)} takes an {@link Object} as its first argument, seemingly
 * this needs to be a {@link FeatureCollection}, which seems to have no way to set a {@code name} attribute.
 * <p>
 * See the question here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/328675
 * <p>
 * This implements an alternative, that inserts the {@code <name/>} element, as soon as it sees the {@code Document}
 * element.
 */
public class NameInsertingDataWriter extends DataWriter {
    private static final String DOCUMENT_ELEMENT = "Document";

    private static final String LOCAL_NAME = "name";

    private static final String Q_NAME = "kml:name";

    private String name;

    public NameInsertingDataWriter(OutputStream outputStream, String name) {
        super(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream), "UTF-8");
        this.name = name;
        setIndentStep("  ");
    }

    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes atts) throws SAXException {
        super.startElement(uri, localName, qName, atts);

        if (DOCUMENT_ELEMENT.equals(localName)) {
            insertNameElement(uri);
        }
    }

    private void insertNameElement(String uri) throws SAXException {
        startElement(uri, LOCAL_NAME, Q_NAME, new AttributesImpl());
        characters(name);
        endElement(uri, LOCAL_NAME, Q_NAME);
    }
}
```